# Fixed texture size in Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I am building quite a complex 3D environment in Three.js (FPS-a-like). For this purpose I wanted to structure the loading of textures and materials in an object oriënted way. For example; `materials.wood.brownplank` is a reusable material with a certain texture and other properties. Below is a simplified visualisation of the process where models uses materials and materials uses textures.

```
loadTextures();
loadMaterials();
loadModels();

//start doing stuff in the scene
```

I want to use that material on differently sized objects. However, in Three.js you can't (AFAIK) set a certain texture scale. You will have to set the repeat to scale it appropiate to your object. But I don't want to do that for every plane of every object I use.

[Here is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1qSf.png)

As you can see, the textures are not uniform in size.

Is there an easy way achieve this? So cloning the texture and/or material every time and setting the repeat according to the geometry won't do :)

I hope someone can help me.

**Conclusion:**

There is no real easy way to do this. I ended up changing my loading methods, where things like `materials.wood.brownplank` are now for example `getMaterial('wood', 'brownplank')` In the function new objects are instantiated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by modifying your geometry UV coordinates according to the "real" dimensions of each face.

In Three.js, UV coordinates are relative to the face and texture (as in, 0.0 = one edge, 1.0 = other edge), no matter what the actual size of texture or face is. But by modifying the UVs in geometry (multiply them by some factor based on face physical size), you can use the same material and texture in different sizes (and orientations) per face.

You just need to figure out the mapping between UVs, geometry scale and your desired working units (eg. mm or m). Sorry I don't have, or know a ready algorithm to do it, but that's the approach you probably need to take. Should be quite doable with a bit of experimentation and google-fu.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong; but aren't the UV coordinates for setting an offset, and not the scale?

Comment: @claarman. Although I'm not very good with UVs, I'm pretty sure you are wrong :) I was just writing a Three.js importer for another geometry format, and incorrectly converted UV coordinates resulted in being in the wrong scale. So yes, they affect both scale, offset and orientation.

Comment: Ok, then I will try your approach ;)

Comment: @claarman Just to be more clear, I'm not talking about `map.offset.*` and friends, which are properties of texture, but geometry UVs, which you can get a handle with `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]`

Comment: It took a little longer than expected before I could continue. But I went with the approach with cloning and settings scales. However, I integrated it in the texture/material/model loading process, and is therefore a minimal effort