# Flexible texture repetition depending on object size in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a question about texture mapping and repeat with THREE.js. In my scene there are several thousands of cubes with different height. All shall have the same material with a texture which shall be repeated depending on the height of the object. Since `repeat.y` isn't the same for each object, I'm afraid I cannot use the same material for all cubes although the texture is the same. Is that right? Or is there a way to use the same material and update the repeat value automatically?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530350/fixed-texture-size-in-three-js/17551618

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. Unfortunately I didn't see that before. I'll try your approach with the UV coordinates first :-)

Comment: It worked out! Just if you want, you could write a short answer so that I can accept it. Anyway thank you very much!